# Структура БД для хранения административных единиц любой страны мира

Tags: mysql, структуры-данных, структуры

**Не могу** хитро (гибко, универсально, надежно, без "твою же **** , надо все сломать чтобы подкорректировать под Зимбабве" ) сконструировать БД для хранения населенных пунктов любой из страны мира. Стандартная структура состоящая из таблиц: "country", "region", "city", и соответствующих полей которые связывают родителя с дочерними элементами здесь не катит.

---

**Проблема** в том, что у каждой страны мира свое разделение на административные единицы, у одной страны это: область, район, город|село|поселок; а в другой: штат, город. [Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC) как бы показывает что у всех стран по 4 уровня вложенности в иерархии админ. единиц, то есть первое, что приходит на ум - не надо привязываться к области|штату а просто к уровню вложенности (админ. единица 1-го уровня, 2-го, 3-го, 4-го), но в таблице в википедии возле колонки 4-го уровня написано "Четвёртый уровень и меньше" - значит это уже не фиксированная иерархия 4-х уровней, а там еще может быть много уровней вложенности, соответственно чем больше глубина, тем больше проблем при получении данных, так как придется лазить туда-сюда по этому дереву.

---

**Буду очень признателен за помощь!** Может кто-то уже решал данную проблему путем набивания шишок и может посоветовать что-то толковое, чтобы я не наступал на те же грабли .

Бд с данными "всех стран" по типу geonames.org не надо советовать, так как там полно муссора и излишних|недостающих данных, на данном этапе мне нужна сама структура таблиц, чтобы нарисовать ее на листочке, и уже хорошенько помозговать какие проблемы могут быть при ее использовании, и как ее заточить под собственные нужды.

Comment: что-то вроде: дерево, у каждого узла id типа, таблица типов с id для каждой страны, и уровень вложенности для этого типа и страны, потом типы мапинга для прикладных / юридических аспектов

Comment: Напрашивается дерево произвольной глубины, для основных данных. Т.е. "id-записи, id-родителя". Вот только напрягает, что у вас MySQL, в нем с деревьями сложно работать. Был бы какой нибудь Postgress ...

Comment: Скачайте базу OpenStreetMap. Там эту проблему уже решили.

Comment: К тому же хочу сказать, что в случае с РФ уровни вложенности могут быть весьма странными. Например, у нас обычно субъект = область. Но есть три города, которым присвоем статус субъектов (Москва, СПб, Байконур). Хотя обычно город-столица субъекта принадлежит ему. Дополнительно у нас существуют края - это то же самое, что и область, но в них существуют АО (почти как отдельная область в области). Что уж говорить про "республики".... Как это красиво передать - неясно. Нужно чертить графическую схему, а не рассуждать о сферических конях....

а города и области могут делиться на районы и МО.

Comment: Дополнительно напомню, что федеральные округа, которые являются как бы надмножествами субъектов... На самом деле, региональное деление нормальных стран существенно проще. Его как раз можно свести к трехуровневой схеме - страна - регион (область, край, медье, штат и т.п.) - город.

Comment: @strangeqargo такого рода мысля меня тоже посетила, но смотрелось оно (на том листе где я все ето нарисовал) не привлекательно, и что-то показывало что можно лучше :)

Comment: @Mike да, проблемма постоения толково дерева имеется, надо чтобы и выборка быстро проходила и вставка/обновление тоже не нагружало

Comment: @gecube что-то я не вижу где там базу выкачать можно? (ткните носом если несложно)

Comment: Откуда качать описалово есть по адресу http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data

Comment: @gecube спасибо, посмотрел, у них все элементы представленны в виде точки (которой могут помечаться и город, и целая старна), линии, полигон ... Там все заточенно сугубо под геолокацию, и под работу с картой, структуры населенных пунков и их иерархии там нет (ну я по крайней мере не нашел) [Структура БД OSM](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/w/images/c/cd/RailsPortModels.png)

Comment: @VladVlad мы когда строили систему определения адресов для таксомоторного парка, использовали три источника - яндекс, гугль и OSM. Поверьте, при некотором навыке, из них всех можно вытянуть саму базу адресов, городов, регионов. И примеров кода вагон и маленькая тележка. 

Смотрите:
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:boundary%3Dadministrative

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23501075/getting-all-cities-in-a-specific-country-using-openstreetmap

Comment: @gecube понял, спасибо, уделю этому больше внимания, просто раньше с картами не приходилось работать, поэтому пока что не знаю с какой стороны к данному функционалу подходить, но думаю ето дело поправимо :)

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле все вырождается в простое хранение графа, потому что это он и есть:

- таблица объектов: id, тип, центр, полигон, метаданные
- таблица связей: id родителя, id ребенка
- (опционально) таблица названий: идентификатор объекта, локаль, название

В общем-то, больше вам ничего и не нужно. Формат административного деления можно забрать прямиком у гугла (у них есть просто administrative_area с пятью уровнями деления, которые и нужны-то не сказать чтобы часто), валидацию структуры объектов у вас никогда не получится сделать (потому что она любит не подчиняться формальным правилам), поэтому остается только использовать общее решение и править руками. Для случаев типа совпадения названия региона и города-столицы региона можно засунуть в метаданные параметр `implicit`, по которому регион просто не будет выводиться, для случаев постоянного обновления региона из какой-нибудь API можно добавить в метаданные параметр `manualUpdate`. Честно говоря, даже не знаю, что дальше посоветовать. Возможно, графовая база данных будет работать лучше, хотя и с обычными скорее всего всё в порядке будет.

Comment: Для начала для себя **уточню** моменты которые не понял: что вы имеете ввиду под "центр" и "полигон"? :) 

Такого вида структура тоже приходила на ум (прозрачная - а ето плюс). Если вы имеете в виду модель постороения дерива "Adjacency List" (стандартная связка "родитель > ребенок"), проблема при работе с такой моделью в том, что нужно использовать рекурсию, которая бомбит БД множеством запросов (а ето минус) :(

Comment: Смотрел в сторону хранения данных через модель "Nested sets", для статической базы самое то (выборка будет проходить одним запросом со скоростью пули), но в связи с тем что здесь данные буду добавляться (хотя бы на первом етапе), при вставке прийдется обновлять множество значений, соответственно таблица будет блокироваться на время прохождения данной операции (скорость: "черепаха с чугунной гирей на спине").
![Nested Set in real life](https://robsite.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/3oc0f8.jpeg).

Comment: Насчет того **"что там у гугл"**, я не натыкался на описания их структуры хранения (или наверное ето показывается при тесной работе с API, как такового описание и нет), пробуя понять как представляет все ето гугл, я использовал геокодирования, в результате наблюдал то, что указываеться (как вы и описали) "administrative_area_level_[n]".

Comment: А теперь **эмулируем ситуацию**: пользователю надо указать свое месторасположения (при регистрации, или при чем то еще), ему надо [допустим] отрисовать селектами ети уровни (у нас на данном етапе данных нет, таблица админ. едениц пустая, есть страны), надо ему показать админ. уровни которые есть в его стране, то есть надо хотя бы отрисовать что нужны: область -> район -> город|село. Соответсвенно ети данные должны быть уже где-то записаны, невзирая на то, что самих населенных пунктов еще нет.

Comment: @VladVlad да, adjacency list, я в способах хранения ветвистых структур в реляционке плаваю и заучил только этот. Как именно вам сохранять связи графа - ваш выбор. По пользователю - ему не нужно указывать конкретно город и село, ему нужно выбрать родительский регион, а затем выбирать из детей выбранного  региона. Если он имеет право создавать, пусть и создает эту структуру.

Comment: я тоже думал урезать все это до 3-х уровней и не мучаться, если не найду решение как организовать "детализацию" (районные центры и прочие промежуточные уровни - в моем случаи было бы конечно лучше если бы поддерживались все эти уровни) населенных пункотов то предполагаю, что сделаю именно так.